# What code formatters are available for Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I need a good formatter for my Erlang code. What are the alternatives? I want the formatter to hook into my `rebar3` build system and also be added as a *post-hook* in git.

[For a great overview, see this table](https://github.com/WhatsApp/erlfmt/blob/master/doc/ErlangFormatterComparison.md) from [WhatsApp/erlfmt](https://github.com/WhatsApp/erlfmt).

Comment: Try to use IntelliJ IDEA - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of formatters coming up lately…

At NextRoll, we created [rebar3 format](https://hex.pm/packages/rebar3_format). It's a configurable formatter that is still under heavy development, but already usable.

There is also [steamroller](https://github.com/old-reliable/steamroller), which is more opinionated.

And there is people working on other non-public-yet formatters.

Check out [this thread in the Elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/steamroller-an-opinionated-erlang-code-formatter/27532) and [this PR in the OTP repo](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2451#issuecomment-554389010).

Comment: See this comparison: https://github.com/WhatsApp/erlfmt/blob/master/doc/ErlangFormatterComparison.md

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at [steamroller](https://github.com/old-reliable/steamroller), also a rebar3 plugin. Steamroller is an opinionated autoformatter similar to the built-in Elixir formatter. Very different from `erl_tidy` and emacs `erlang-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is erl_tidy, which comes as a rebar plugin:

https://github.com/tsloughter/erl_tidy

By default it does not override existing files. Instead, `module.erl` become `module.erl.bak`, but AFAIR it can be configured.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is [erlang-mode](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html) style of formatting, you may take a look at [fenollp/erlang-formatter](https://github.com/fenollp/erlang-formatter), it can be used as a rebar3 plugin, or can be used in Makefile.

Please refer to the README of that repo for more details.